# .NET as client, java as server

Tags: .net

I am planning to use .NET Client along with a Java Server.

Are there any options / tools which help in .NET to Java connectivity apart from programming against web services.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few I've seen for .NET to Java interop:

JIntegra:  http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/

JNBridge:  http://www.jnbridge.com/

These seem to be pretty expansive and flexbile, but also expensive.  Achieving true interop between Java and .NET can be a bit involved.  If XML-based web services are an option, that might be the easiest route.

One slightly unrelated technology is IKVM.NET http://www.ikvm.net/ - this tool allows you to compile Java bytecode into .NET IL (e.g. compile a .jar into a .NET DLL), so that you can use compiled Java code "natively" with .NET.  This isn't necessarily good for interop, but a cool technology none-the-less.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a socket with XML message passing.  Both Java and .NET have rich abilities to marshal and unmarshal XML.

Answer (score 1):

**Take a look at Thrift (apache project)...**  It was developed at facebook, and claims:

> Thrift is a software framework for scalable cross-language services development. It combines a software stack with a code generation engine to build services that work efficiently and seamlessly between C++, **Java**, Python, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl, Haskell, **C#**, Cocoa, Smalltalk, and OCaml.

http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/

Answer (score 0):

- WebServices: preferred
- JNBridge: see [this](http://www.devx.com/interop/Article/19945/1954?pf=true)
- DB or Messaging: see [this](http://www.devx.com/interop/Article/19952/1954?pf=true) (could be suited for older versions, robotics etc)